# replacing menu item with icon in Wordpress

Tags: html, css

I have a menu which is controlled through Wordpress admin, and I want to create one of the links to use a font-awesome icon. I know how to add a custom css to the menu item, but not sure how to make it show an icon instead of a text name (in the Navigation Label)

EDIT -

[image]

I have a class .login with

```
.login {
  font-family: 'fontawesome';
  display: block;
  content: '\f077';
}
```

but nothing shows

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to insert a FontAwesome image with CSS (rather than using the HTML `<i class="fa">` system, then you'll need to use a code snippet like the following:

```
#myMenuItemIcon{
   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
   content: '\f19a';
}
```

The `content` setting comes from the [Icon Page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/wordpress/) on the main website. Use the unicode equivalent (`f19a` in this instance) and set it as the element's content.

Without seeing/knowing more about your menu CSS, I can't provide a more detailed or specific answer.

Comment: I assume that is what needs to happen. I have to insert my title names into the Wordpress admin menu panel. and I guess I need to leave the content blank and insert it through css instead